# $l_{\infty}$ convergence of OLS prediction error

Tags: statistics, regression, estimation, linear-regression

I have found many resources talking about the $l_2$ convergence of OLS estimation error and prediction error.

I have also read about the analysis of the $l_2$ convergence of lasso estimation error and prediction error, variable selection consistency, and $l_{\infty}$ convergence of lasso estimation error. Suppose I'm dealing with linear functions, then I can easily use the $l_{\infty}$ convergence of lasso estimation error to get a $l_{\infty}$ convergence of lasso prediction error, which must has the term $||X||_{\infty}$ involved.

My goal is to study the analysis of the $l_{\infty}$ convergence of OLS prediction error for more general functions. However I didn't find any relevant resources yet. To that end, I was hoping to find some textbook discuss the $l_{\infty}$ convergence on linear functions. But all I can find is the $l_2$ convergence of the prediction error. Then I think maybe I can just target on studying the $l_{\infty}$ convergence of estimation error, and then use the device $||X(\hat{\theta} - \theta^*)||_{\infty} \le ||X||_{\infty}  ||\hat{\theta} - \theta^*||_{\infty}$.

However, I couldn't find any resources talking about the $l_{\infty}$ convergence of OLS estimation error. May I ask for any advice?

I understand the reason why the majority of textbooks focus on teaching the $l_2$ convergence - because the underlying objective is the means square error. Therefore, it makes sense to measure how close the mean response $X \hat{\theta}$ to the true parameter $X\theta^*$ in terms of $l_2$ error. But my goal is to understand the upper bound of the entries of $X(\hat{\theta} - \theta^*)$.

Comment: I'm confused by the wording of this question. To me, "$\ell_2$ convergence" or "$L_2$ convergence" typically means convergence in the $\ell_2$ or $L_2$ norm. In the present context, I would interpret that as convergence of a sequence of random vector. But you are asking about "the upper bound of the entries" (which should be **least** upper bound), which is not the $L_\infty$ norm of a random vector. It's the biggest absolute value of a coordinate in a vector. But your vector is a random vector, so $X(\hat{\theta}-\theta^*)$ is random. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @jwhite Indeed my question is not clear enough. Thank you for pointing it out. Since I'm interested in studying the upper bound of the largestg absolute value among all the coordinates in random vector $X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)$, it's natural to look at the $l_{\infty}$ norm of that. Meanwhile, since I'm working with random vector, I'm just interested in knowing high probability statement. For example, with some high probability, the largest absolute value of the coordinate of random vector $X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)$ is bounded by ..

Comment: Hmm. If we want limit behavior, we have $\|\cdot\|_{\ell_\infty}\leqslant \|\cdot\|_{\ell_2}$ for vectors in Euclidean space. So if $\ell_2$ convergence is interpreted as $\|X(\hat{\theta}-\theta^*)\|_{\ell_2}\underset{p}{\to}0$, we have the same thing for $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: This could also give suboptimal bounds for a particular sample size (rather than in the limit) by noting that if $X$ is the design matrix, $\hat{\theta}-\theta^*$ has mean zero and covariance matrix $(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2$, under the model $\theta=X\beta+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ a white noise $WN(\sigma^2)$ process. Then it may be easier to get high probability statements on $\|X(\hat{\theta}-\theta^*)\|_{\ell_2}$ and use the bound $\|\cdot\|_{\ell_\infty}\leqslant \|\cdot\|_{\ell_2}$.

Comment: If we want optimal bounds, a quick search for the distribution of the maximum of correlated normal random variables makes me think this is an unsolved problem even for normal variables.

Comment: @jwhite Thank you for your comment! It is very helpful. Now as I'm thinking, I can either use the fact that the $||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{\infty} \le ||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{2}$, or $ ||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{\infty} \le ||X||_{\infty}||\hat \theta - \theta^*||_{\infty}$. It is true that the entries of $X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)$ are correlated - because each of them depend on using the same estimator $\hat \theta $, and it is hard to find the distribution of the largest absolute maximum, but I still think there might be resources about $||\hat \theta - \theta^*||_{\infty}$.

Comment: @jwhite May I ask if you have any intuition on whether the bound of $||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{\infty} \le ||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{2}$ or $ ||X(\hat \theta - \theta^*)||_{\infty} \le ||X||_{\infty}||\hat \theta - \theta^*||_{\infty}$ is tighter?

Comment: Yes, the entries of $X(\hat{\theta}-\theta^*)$ will generally be correlated. In OLS, the entries of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ will also usually be correlated.

I don't have anything to base this on, but my intuition would be that the $\|X(\hat{\theta}-\theta^*)\|_\infty\leqslant \|X\|_\infty\|\hat{\theta}-\theta^*\|_\infty$ would usually be tighter, but that the other inequality would lead to something easier to explicitly calculate.